# Date sql query, java

Tags: java, sql, date

I'm trying to execute a query in SQL where I need the day, month and year of "today".

```
INSERT INTO Facture (Date_Achat,Remise, Acompte, Mode_De_Paiement, N°Client) VALUES (Date(Now()), "
                +s6+","+ s7 +" ,'"+s8+"' ,"+s1+"); "
```

However `Date(Now)` doesn't work and I tried this in order to put "actuelle" in place of `Date(Now())` but doesn't work. So, how can I "replace" `Date(Now())` in the following statement by today's date BUT only day, month and year?

```
Date actuelle = new Date();

//String dat = dateFormat.format(actuelle);
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.YEAR);
try {
    actuelle = formatter.parse(today.toString());
}
catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CréationFacture.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL I take it? What is the type of the `Date_Achat` column, and what specifically happens when you run your query -- does it return an error message, does it insert data you don't want? "Doesn't work" is not helpful.

Comment: You should really, really do yourself a great favor and change that code to make use of `PreparedStatements`. Then this date formatting mess becomes superfluous anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DO NOT** use string concatenation to insert string values into a SQL statement, unless you want to make your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, where hackers can **steal your data** and **delete your tables**.

Use a `PreparedStatement`.

---

If you're on Java 8, using [`LocalDate.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now--) is the easiest way to get today's date.

So, your code should be something like below, using meaningful variable names instead of obscure names like `s6`.

You should of course adjust the `setXxx()` calls for the actual data types of your variables.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Facture" +
            " (Date_Achat, Remise, Acompte, Mode_De_Paiement, N°Client)" +
            " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setDate  (1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));
    stmt.setInt   (2, remise);
    stmt.setInt   (3, acompte);
    stmt.setString(4, modeDePaiement);
    stmt.setInt   (5, noClient);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

---

If you can't use `LocalDate`, get a `java.sql.Date` object like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year  = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day   = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.clear();
cal.set(year, month, day);
java.sql.Date today = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Then use that in the first setter call:

```
stmt.setDate(1, today);
```

Comment: Really Thanks Andreas, it works super-well ! You explain things very clearly and simply, hope you could help me if I have any problem in the future. Thanks again!